# Version 8.0 integrates but Version 9.0.1 doesn't

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, version-9, version-8

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.1**

---

I am trying to run the following integral in version 9.0, but it fails:

```
Integrate[
 2 I (-1 + 
  x) ((-8 + 12 x - 6 mπ^2 x - 2 mπ^2 x^2 - 
   4 x^3)/((1 - x)^2 + 
   mπ^2 x) + ((4 - 2 x + 4 mπ^2 x - 8 x^2 + 
   6 mπ^2 x^2 + 6 x^3) Log[
    1/((1 - x)^2 + mπ^2 x)])/((1 - x)^2 + mπ^2 x)), {x, 0, 
  1}, Assumptions -> mπ > 0 && mπ < .1]
```

Version 9.0.1:
[image: Version 9.0]

But in version 8.0, it works:

[image]

Is this a bug, or is the integral really non-convergent?  What's a possible workaround, since I don't have easy v8 access?

Comment: BTW shouldn't there a space between m and pi, or is this intentional?

Comment: $m\pi$ represents a single symbol.

Comment: I can reproduce this, but in future, please **do not** use the bugs tag until a few users have confirmed the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing; I have removed the bugs tag.

Comment: Got the same as you both in 8 and 9, and the integral doesn't look non-convergent.

Comment: Thanks god 2πR  can't be used as a symbol name

Comment: Notice that the indefinite integration `int = Integrate[..., {x,0,1}]` works and then doing `(int /. x -> 1) - (int /. x -> 0)` will reproduce the result from version 8.

Comment: Appears to be working again in the development Mathematica kernel. I filed a bug report so it should become a test in case. Which might be useful if it manages to rebreak itself.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau any news on this?

Comment: @Loius I get `(2*I)*(1 - 3*mπ^2 + 3*mπ^2*(-2*Log[mπ] + 
    mπ*(Sqrt[4 - mπ^2]*(ArcTan[mπ/Sqrt[4 - mπ^2]] - 
        ArcTan[(-2 + mπ^2)/(mπ*Sqrt[4 - mπ^2])]) + mπ*Log[mπ])))` in my current build.

Comment: 10.1 gives a result about 6 lines long with a bunch of `Log` terms, that numerically seems to be equivalent to Dan's expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, this problem has been fixed in version 10.  The result in version 10.3 is:

[image]